# cannot insert file detail into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, dropzone.js

I dont know why i cannot insert filename into MySQL.
I tried many different approaches but still does not work.
I can only move the image to the "uploads" file but the "insert" query seems not workable.
Please someone can help me? Many thanks.

**editprofile.php**

```
<form  action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' class="dropzone" id="mydropzone">
                        </form>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="upload">Submit</button>
```

**javascript**

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $("#mydropzone").dropzone({
        url: 'upload.php',
        acceptedFiles: "image/*",
        dictDefaultMessage: '<h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></i><br>drag images here</h4>or click to select',
        maxFiles: 1,
        maxFilesize: 10,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        removedfile: function(file) { 
            var fileRef;
            return (fileRef = file.previewElement) != null ? fileRef.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
        },
        init: function() {
            var submitButton = document.querySelector("#upload");
            mydropzone = this;
            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
                alert("Only one image file accepted.");
                this.removeFile(file);
            })
            $("#upload").hide();
            submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                mydropzone.processQueue();
            });
            this.on("addedfile", function() {
                $("#upload").show();
            });
        }
    });
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 

$storeFolder = 'uploads';  

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];                    

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds; 

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name']; 


    if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile)){
        $SQL = "INSERT INTO member_photo (member_id,filename) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user_session']."','".$targetFile."')";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        if(!$result) echo "SQL: ", $SQL, "<br />ERROR: ", mysql_error();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: In "member_photo" table, columns contain (photoID,member_id,filename,date). photoID auto increment and date also

Comment: I cannot see the database connectivity code in your file.  Can you please print the $SQL statement and try to insert using phpmyadmin. Then you can see if there any issue with database connectivity.

Comment: Also you can use mysql_error() to check what error it is producing. $result = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());;

Comment: i can use insert query in phpmyadmin. Also the connection is fine because i can login / register in website

Comment: so there is no problem in query. just try  $result = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error($con)) and check is there any error . $con is your database connection var

Comment: there is no error msg show off in my screen . And the image can be moved into "uploads" folder. I dont know what happen.